# Localhost sends no data after mamp install

Tags: apache, localhost, mamp, macos-sierra

I am new to Mac and am trying to move a project I was working on with WAMP onto my Mac. After installing Bitnami MAMP and booting up my computer for the first time, I cannot access localhost through the browser to view my webpage. (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONCE)

I have tried reinstalling MAMP twice, and have changed nothing from the default installation. I have been doing research online, but have found nothing that has helped me thus far, some details:

-I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.2
-MAMP is installed in my applications folder
-I can ping localhost 
-My apache server is running, and I have checked that there isn't another Apache service trying to run
-In my Apache2 error log, the following error appears:[core:notice] [pid 2302] AH00052: child pid 2305 exit signal Bus error (10)
(I assume this is another way of saying segmentation fault)
-I have tried running localhost in Safari and Chrome
-I have made sure I am connecting with the right port (8080)
-My google chrome error log:Failed to load resource (ERR_FAILED)

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern:
I have found a solution to my problem, it is really quite simple

1.Uninstall Bitnami MAMP

2.Never touch that hot garbage ever again

There are other MAMP stacks out there that work much better. I wasted nearly half a work day on this, or, if you have the time, just install everything manually